# react-native-google-places : Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2

Tags: android, react-native, google-api, google-places

I use react-native-google-places, I followed the doc and it works perfectly on ios.

On the other hand on android I have this error:

```
Build failed with an exception.
 What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-google-places'.
      > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-google-places:_debugPublishCopy'.
         > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2.
           Searched in the following locations:
               file:/Users/Manu/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/11.6.2/play-services-base-11.6.2.pom
               file:/Users/Manu/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/11.6.2/play-services-base-11.6.2.jar
               file:/Users/Manu/Desktop/AwesomeProject/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/11.6.2/play-services-base-11.6.2.jar
               file:/Users/Manu/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/11.6.2/play-services-base-11.6.2.pom
               file:/Users/Manu/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/11.6.2/play-services-base-11.6.2.jar
               file:/Users/Manu/Desktop/AwesomeProject/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/11.6.2/play-services-base-11.6.2.jar
           Required by:
               AwesomeProject:react-native-google-places:unspecified
         > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.2.
           Searched in the following locations:
               file:/Users/Manu/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-places/11.6.2/play-services-places-11.6.2.pom
...
```

ps: I also have update android studio today

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, my solusion is add this line to file **android/build.gradle** :

```
 maven {
       url 'https://maven.google.com'
   }
```

Sorry For My Bad English :(

Comment: Are you sure  your **android/build.gradle** like this : 
https://github.com/maslhiro/ToolBarWithDrawer_RN/blob/master/android/build.gradle
If  it doen't work ,u can clone my repo in git : https://github.com/maslhiro/ToolBarWithDrawer_RN
hope it useful to you

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by dependencies versions from google places and the packages.

You can solve this by following the below steps.

1.open /node_modules/react-native-google-places/android/build.gradle

update the previous code from

```
 compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
 compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
 compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
```

to change like this

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
```

now build the apk again with the command

```
react-native run-android
```

It will solve the problem.I hope it will be useful for some other members.Thank you.